# Spreadsheet formula to lookup across multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

How to look up a value in multiple columns and then extract the corresponding relative value. 
example: there are (100rows x 3columns) x 5 sets next to next with name, phone, email. so search for phone(unique), and return the corresponding name.

Vlookup performs only one column
match takes on one row or column

[Sample sheet attached](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DGs8Y4XtJ4bUc6PDUuEtQXx6A5s5AMek5VBvGatSFik/edit#gid=605682441)
Need values in the 2nd sheet

Answer (score 1):

To perform multiple criteria in a `VLOOKUP`, the easiest way would be to create a helper column. For example, you can concatenate all the parameters you want to include as criteria with a character like the underscore `_`, and perform a `VLOOKUP` with the key also concatenated.

You can also do it without helper columns if you combine `INDEX` and `MATCH`. To do this, it's set up the same way as a single-criteria `INDEX`/`MATCH`, except the `MATCH` is set up to search for `1` as a key, with the lookup array being `(condition_range1=condition1)*(condition_range2=condition2)*...`.

I've set up an example showing both techniques here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12viS6lkaokXs-G6Wl4UU7H6-wmNX_79XYm-JCPPSBdU

Comment: I wanted to search in multiple columns and not return multiple values... The return value would be single.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I've edited the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

paste in **Sheet2!C3** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3:A, 
 {Sheet1!B:H; Sheet1!I:O; Sheet1!P:V; Sheet1!W:AC; Sheet1!AD:AJ; Sheet1!AK:AQ}, 
 {3, 4, 5, 7}, 0)))
```

[image: 0]